# how to analyze necessary/sufficient relationship?

Tags: correlation, psychometrics, pearson-r, nonlinear

I'm a second year psych grad student. From my fascination with formal logic, I wondered (just personal; not homework) about how to statistically establish necessary/sufficient relationships between variables.

Let's suppose two variables, Intelligence and Creativity, whose relationship is summarized by the conditional, "if creative, then intelligent".

So on the high end of Intelligence, we find the full spectrum of Creativity; but on the low end of Intelligence, we find only low levels of Creativity. We can say that Intelligence is a necessary (but not sufficient) condition for Creativity, while Creativity is a sufficient (but not necessary) condition for Intelligence.

Two questions:

(1) I imagine the scatter plot for Intelligence and Creativity would look like a right triangle whose non-hypotenuse legs are perpendicular to the axes. If Intelligence is on the x-axis, then the right angle would be at the +x,-y corner. Is this correct?

[image]

(2) If I imagined it correctly, what formula or procedure do I use to objectively measure how well data follows such a relationship? Is there an already-established way for dealing with this? My psych professor once told me that there is actually such a relationship between Intelligence and Creativity, but when I asked how to measure it, he said something only to the effect of "look at the scatter plot". All I know is that Pearson correlation is inappropriate, as the relationship is not linear. But I don't want to just look at the scatter plot.

It's my first time to post here, so please be patient with me.

Comment: @GraemeWalsh Maybe you misunderstood. What I meant by the "full spectrum Of Creativity" is all from the minimum value to the maximum value. So on the high end of Intelligence, we have observations from the lowest level of Creativity to the highest level. I think that makes us in agreement that there are cases of "being highly intelligent and having zero creativity".
But in case what I imagined is still wrong, would you know how to test any necessary/sufficient relationship?